# Why Google Chrome browsers use -webkit-* prefix, while Chrome runs on Blink (except IOS, where they run on webkit)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

So, do Blink team and Webkit work together on new features? If not, why it's same prefix for both engines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Chrome used to use Webkit until Chrome 28 when it was replaced with Blink, a fork of Webkit. Whilst using Webkit, Chrome had access to all `-webkit-` prefixes.

When the change to Blink was made, the development team decided not to add any new vendor prefixes to the Blink engine. Vendor prefixes are intended to let web developers try out new standards until such time as they are properly implemented, and the Chrome team felt that this could be better done by enabling/disabling an un-prefixed version of the feature from within the browser. The Chromium site [states](https://www.chromium.org/blink#vendor-prefixes):

> ...instead of enabling a feature by default with a vendor prefix, we
>   will instead keep the (unprefixed) feature behind the “enable
>   experimental web platform features” flag in `about:flags` until
>   the feature is ready to be enabled by default.

For compatibility reasons the old `-webkit-` prefixes were retained in Blink (removing support would break sites that relied on Webkit prefixes). Due to the above reason they were not replaced with Blink specific counterparts, and since Chrome 28 no new prefixes have been (or will be) added.